# How do you output second derivatives or output the Wiener Process used in ItoProcess?

Tags: differential-equations, stochastic-calculus

I have a system of stochastic differential equations and I use ItoProcess to solve them. The following is a snippet in which this is done.

```
ParallelTable[
  proc = ItoProcess[{\[DifferentialD]x1[t] == 
       a[[1]] \[DifferentialD]t + 
        b[[1]] \[DifferentialD]w[t], \[DifferentialD]x2[t] == 
       a[[2]] \[DifferentialD]t + 
        b[[2]] \[DifferentialD]w[t], \[DifferentialD]x3[t] == 
       a[[3]] \[DifferentialD]t + 
        b[[3]] \[DifferentialD]w[t], \[DifferentialD]x4[t] == 
       a[[4]] \[DifferentialD]t + b[[4]] \[DifferentialD]w[t]} /. 
     Join[{d -> \[CapitalEta][[i]]}, para], {x1[t], x2[t], x3[t], 
     x4[t]}, {{x1, x2, x3, x4}, {0, 0, 0, 0}}, {t, 0}, 
    w \[Distributed] WienerProcess[]];
  td = RandomFunction[proc, {0., time, dt}, 70];
  data = td["Values", All][[All]];
  X2 = data[[All, All, 2]];
  X3 = data[[All, All, 3]];
  X4 = data[[All, All, 4]];
  X1 = data[[All, All, 1]];
  X2dot = Differences[Transpose[X2]]/dt;
  X4dot = Differences[Transpose[X4]]/dt;
  {X1[[All, time/dt + 1]], X2[[All, time/dt + 1]], 
   X3[[All, time/dt + 1]], X4[[All, time/dt + 1]], 
   X2dot[[time/dt, All]], X4dot[[time/dt, All]]}
  , {j, 1, 128}, {i, 1, Length[\[CapitalEta]]}];
```

My issue is I need to output the accelerations or specifically the derivatives of X4 and X2. Or I can calculate the accelerations from the equations of motion if I can output the wiener process used.

Can anyone help me in accomplishing this?

Comment: You can replace `{x1[t], x2[t], x3[t], x4[t]}` with `{x1[t], x2[t], x3[t], x4[t], x4''[t], x2''[t]}`.

Comment: @b.gates.you.know.what Interesting, I did not see that in the documentation.  Does this also work for the wiener process w[t]?

Comment: It is documented, see e.g. last usage at the top of the [docs](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ItoProcess.html?q=ItoProcess) and the examples.